# How to sort after dehydrate creates all data in Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to BookResource to perform join (book table with author table) with dedydrate(...) function. Final result should be sorted by table Author.

dehydrate(...) is called for each item in Book table.

```
    class Author(Model) 
      author_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Book(Model)
      author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
      book_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class BookResource(ModelResource):

      class Meta(object):
        # The point here is Book table can be sorted. But, final result 
        # should be sorted by author_name
        queryset = Book.objects.all().order_by('book_name')
        resource_name = 'api_test'
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['xml', 'json'])
        allowed_methods = ('get')
        always_return_data = True

      def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        author_id = bundle.obj.author.id  # author is foreign key of book
        author_obj = Author.objects.get(id=bundle.obj.author.id)
        # Construct queryset with author_name. Same as join 2 tables.
        # But, I want to sort by author.
        bundle.data['author_name'] = author_obj.author_name
        return bundle

      # This is called before dehydrate(...) is called. Not sure how to use it.
      def apply_sorting(self, obj_list, options=None):
        return obj_list
```

Questions:

1) How to sort result by author if using above code?

2) Could not figure out how to do join. Can you provide alternative?

Thank you.

Comment: I am in the same boat... With no solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I ran into this lately. If you look at the Tastypie resource on the [dehydrate method](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html)
there is a series of methods called. Shortly, this is the order of calls:

- build_bundle
- obj_get_list
- apply_sorting
- paginators
- full_dehydrate (field by field)
- alter_list_data_to_serialize
- return self.create_response

You want to focus on the second last method `self.alter_list_data_to_serialize(request, to_be_serialized)`
the base method returns the second parameter

```
    def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    """
    A hook to alter list data just before it gets serialized & sent to the user.

    Useful for restructuring/renaming aspects of the what's going to be
    sent.

    Should accommodate for a list of objects, generally also including
    meta data.
    """
    return data
```

Whatever you want to do you can do it in here. Consider that to be serialized format will be a dict with 2 fields: meta and objects. the object field has a list of bundle objects.

An additional sorting layer could be:

```
    def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    try:
        sord = True if request.GET.get("sord") == "asc" else False
        data["objects"].sort(
            key=lambda x: x.data[request.GET.get("sidx", default_value)],
            reverse=sord)
    except:
        pass
    return data
```

You can optimize it as is a bit dirt. But that's the main idea.
Again, it's a workaround and all the sorting should belong to apply_sorting